# Calling an Existing Axios Function in another Function

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to call an existing function that makes an API request using axios in another function which also makes an API request but its unable to execute the function called. I'm relatively new to axios and react so I'm not sure if I'm missing something here and your help would be much appreciated. Also please note, I can call the API again via axios in the second function but instead of repeating the code I would rather like to do function call.

Function 1:

```
export const getUsers = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const resp = await axiosInstance.get("/api/users/");
        dispatch({ type: GET_USERS, payload: resp.data });

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(returnErrors(error.response.data, error.response.status));
    }
}
```

Function 2:

```
export const deactivateUser = (userID) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.put(`/api/user/disable/${userID}/`);
        dispatch(createMessage({ deactivateUser: res.data }));


    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(returnErrors(error.response.data, error.response.status));
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is following:

```
export const deactivateUser = (userID) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.put(`/api/user/disable/${userID}/`);
        dispatch(createMessage({ deactivateUser: res.data }));
        getUsers(); // This is not getting called....

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(returnErrors(error.response.data, error.response.status));
    }
}
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: its not working because getUsers is a function that return function with dispatch arg that its not passed when you call only getUsers()
have you tried dispatch(getUsers())?

Comment: Yes you are right! It worked.. Thanks a lot :)